# Unable to connect to server with DJI iOS SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm attempting to run the [Swift Sample Code](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/tree/1cf3307643d729f2361394eef2243f12fdcd4e6f/Sample%20Code/SwiftSampleCode) project on my iPad. I put in my app key in `StartupViewController.swift`, made the necessary changes to `info.plist` as detailed [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/DJI-SDK-iOS) and changed the appbut when I try to run the app an alert box pops up saying

```
Error:The metadata received from server is invalid, please 
reconnect to the server and try.(code:-14)
```

Is this an issue with a server belonging to DJI or is there something I've missed on my end? (Yes, my iPad's internet connection works)

Comment: (Duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556099/dji-mobile-sample-sdk-android-sdk-registration-failed-dji-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that the bundle id is unique to your app and the bundle id/app key combination is registered in your account at [developer.dji.com](http://developer.dji.com)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have registered your app and placed your registered app id in viewdidload.
-Also in the info.plist you have make schema for dji-protocols used 
You can find this in any of tutorial provided by DJI SDK
http://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/P4MissionsDemo.html