# DJI Mobile Sample Sdk Android - Sdk Registration Failed [dji-sdk]

Tags: android, metadata, registration, dji-sdk

I'm trying to run the Dji Mobile-Sdk-Android : https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android using the instructions on the dji website : https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/quick-start/index.html#android-sample-app

I have registered a developer account, created an application added the API key into the following field

`<meta-data
    android:name="com.dji.sdk.API_KEY"
    android:value="" />`

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I exported the application as a .apk file and installed it on a Oneplus 6T, but when I start the application I'm getting the following erorr message : "Sdk Registration Failed. Please check the bundle ID and your network connectivity.The metadata received from server is invalid, please reconnect to the server and try"

I made sure that the bundle ID from the app page matches the package name in the Android studio and I have internet connection when I run the application and it's still not working.

Did anyone else encounter this before?

Comment: The package name of the GitHub sample is "com.dji.sdk.sample". Did you provide the same name while creating the API KEY in developer site?

Comment: I had to reinstall my Android Studio & android sdk and  using that package it worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have internet connection for the first time.

Comment: I had Internet connection, the problem was solved using the suggestion in the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my side. Here are the suggestions:

1. Make sure your phone has internet connection, try use browser app to view webpage, and switch to WiFi/4G network and try
2. Make sure you create a correct App Key from DJI Developer Website using the package name of your Android Studio project
3. If you are a Basic membership developer on developer website, you will have 20 mobile app activations limitation. You can upgrade to Pro membership to unlock the limitation. Please check this page: https://developer.dji.com/user/membership/

Comment: mentioned that a internet connection is required. What about on a DJI Spark when you connect to the UAV via WiFi? My testing tablet does not have cellular connectivity...

Answer (score 0):

There are **two places** where you should enter your own package name:

In the manifest:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.yyy">
```

And in the app build.gradle!

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
```

Besides, as said above make sure you insert the App Key you generated on DJI developer website.

(Thanks to SChalice)
https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=173866&page=1#pid1791780

Note: to remind this, I always insert the following code in "onRegister" callback:

```
public void onRegister(DJIError djiError) {
    if (djiError == DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
        // startConnectionToProduct
    } else {
        if (djiError == DJISDKError.INVALID_METADATA) {
            // https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=173866&page=1#pid1791780
            Log.e(TAG, "onRegister():\n" + 
                "DJISDKError.INVALID_METADATA -> ensure com.xxx.yyy is coherent in the following places:\n" +
                "In build.gradle:\n" + 
                "    android{defaultConfig{applicationId \"com.xxx.yyy\"\n" + 
                "In AndroidManifest.xml:\n" + 
                "    <manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'\n" + 
                "        package=\"com.xxx.yyy\"");
        } else // treat any other error
    }
}
```